# Permission denied when updating Cloud Code SDK

Tags: parse-platform

For some reason getting the following when typing in 'parse update' into the console.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 162, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "/usr/local/bin/parse/__main__.py", line 6, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/bin/parse/main.py", line 708, in main
  File "/usr/local/bin/parse/main.py", line 515, in handle_update
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

Any ideas?

Comment: what platform?..  i'd run 'sudo parse update' instead, since it looks like you put it in /usr/bin

Comment: That seemed to have prevented the error, but still doesn't update the SDK. Plus the documentation parse.com says only to type in 'parse update'

Comment: update the sdk or the command-line tool?..  you can update the version of javascript used in cloud code by editing config/global.json

Comment: @Fosco Yeah ended up just setting the SDK to the newer version via command line

Answer (score 2):

Inside your terminal, use cd to yourProjectName/CloudCode/ then type in

curl -s https://www.parse.com/downloads/cloud_code/installer.sh | sudo /bin/bash

This worked for me. Hope it will help others.

Answer (score 0):

Can just set the SDK version using the following:

https://parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide#clt-version